# file_get_contents при использовании метода market.add в API вконтакте возвращает 400 Bad Request

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Выполняя в php:
`file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/market.add?owner_id=-135861578&name=test&description=test%20description&category_id=1&price=777&main_photo_id=456239036&access_token=ЗДЕСЬ_РАБОТАЮЩИЙ_КЛЮЧ');`

получаю ошибку **failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request**.

Однако заходя по это же ссылке самостоятельно через браузер, **НЕ** меняя access_token:
[https://api.vk.com/method/market.add?owner_id=-135861578&name=test&description=test%20description&category_id=1&price=777&main_photo_id=456239036&access_token=ЗДЕСЬ_РАБОТАЮЩИЙ_КЛЮЧ](https://api.vk.com/method/market.add?owner_id=-135861578&name=test&description=test%20description&category_id=1&price=777&main_photo_id=456239036&access_token=%D0%97%D0%94%D0%95%D0%A1%D0%AC_%D0%A0%D0%90%D0%91%D0%9E%D0%A2%D0%90%D0%AE%D0%A9%D0%98%D0%99_%D0%9A%D0%9B%D0%AE%D0%A7)

выдаётся нужный результат, то есть всё работает.
Исполнение других предыдущих методов, как загрузка и сохранение фотографии через file_get_contents работало без проблем. В чём проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего не работает из-за пробела в description. Уберите пробел и проверьте работает ли запрос, если да, то используйте urlencode.